# Nextcord: How to DM user without relying on on_message event or command?

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I am making a script which monitors a site for updates. Once it has detected a change, it should DM a user on Discord to notify that there is an update.

Unfortunately, I am unable to find a way of DM'ing a user without a command or on_message event.

This is what I have tried:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands

intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name} ({bot.user.id})")

async def send_dm():
    user = await bot.get_user("0123456789")
    await user.send("hi")

bot.loop.create_task(send_dm())

bot.run("t")
```

This code spits out an error which I don't really understand:

> AttributeError: '_MissingSentinel' object has no attribute 'request'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `fetch_user` work in place of `get_user`?

Comment: @Mous no sadly, it still prints the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The ID argument in

```py
await bot.get_user()
```

should be an integer, not a string.
If you change

```py
user = await bot.get_user("0123456789")
```

to

```py
user = await bot.get_user(0123456789) #no quotation marks
```

then it should work.